# Understand cross domain stuff and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss, same-origin-policy

I am a bit confused about 2 things related to cross domain stuff.

Say I have 2 domains; mydomain.com and otherdomain.com

Now on mydomain.com, what all are the allowed things that can be accessed from otherdomain.com ?
I mean can we have

```
<img src="otherdomain.com/xyz.jpg">
```

Similarly can we directly use otherdomain.com in iframe src ? What all are allowed by default? 
What can be done to prevent access from otherdomain.com's perespective ?

2nd part is related to JavaScript/AJAX.
Is otherdomain stuff blocked by default in script related thing ?
Using AJAX, can I by default make a requst to otherdomain.com ? Is it allowed? What can be done to get response from otherdomain.com, if it is not allowed ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript It answers all your questions.

Comment: Yes I have already read that and lots of other things...but got confused by diff sources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You cannot read from another domain (unless it allows you to).

You can display or execute content from another domain (eg, using an image, frame, or script tag), but you can't read it directly from your code.
Thus, you cannot send an AJAX request to another domain, and you cannot read the contents of an image, frame, or script tag that was loaded from another domain.

Comment: Actually, you can use AJAX with another domain if the other domain is set up properly--a technology called [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: @TedHopp: That's why I said `unless it allows you to`.

Comment: It wasn't clear that the qualifier applied to your last sentence. It could be interpreted to apply to `<img>` tags, for instance. (A server can block access to any resource based on the referring page.)

Comment: Actually you can make an ajax request. But only read the response if allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> what all are the allowed things that can be accessed from otherdomain.com?  I mean can we have `<img src="otherdomain.com/xyz.jpg">`

You need to distinguish between "show" and "access". You can include the image, but you cannot access it's data because of the [same-origin-policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

> Similarly can we directly use otherdomain.com in iframe src? What all are allowed by default?

You can include everything that can be linked, from stylesheets, scripts, images to whole pages via frames. Executing scripts from other domains is actually a standard method for getting data, called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP); and including resources from third-party-CDNs is common as well.

> What can be done to prevent access from otherdomain.com's perespective?

You can use the [`X-FRAME-OPTIONS`-header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to prevent inclusion via frames, which should be respected by the most browsers.

You could try to avoid answering requests (sending 404 content) with the wrong `REFERER` header, but that's not a reliable method since REFERER is often disabled by browsers or blocked by firewalls.

> 2nd part is related to JavaScript/AJAX. Is otherdomain stuff blocked by default in script related thing ? Using AJAX, can I by default make a requst to otherdomain.com ? Is it allowed?

No, the access to the data is blocked. You can send the request, but the response will not be available to your script unless [CORS headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) are sent to explicitly allow it.

> What can be done to get response from otherdomain.com, if it is not allowed ?

You can use a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) on mydomain.com.

Comment: Thx a lot...Could you pls be more detailed on points you have said...like when you said cannot access image data..what does that mean ? Also for remote script execution, is JSONP the only option ? Also how do I actually implement X-FRAME-OPTIONS ? Also how do I set the CORS headers to allow access from other domain ?

Comment: By "image data" I mean accessing the pixel data, e.g. when drawing the image onto a canvas. "remote script execution" can be any arbitrary script, JSONP is just a application of it. For the other things, search for some tutorials/SO questions regarding them, there's a lot of info about them on the web.

Answer (score 0):

> can we have `<img src="otherdomain.com/xyz.jpg">`

Yes we can have this and any of other resources like images, videos and audio files, zip, pdf ...

> can we directly use otherdomain.com in iframe src ?
>
> can I by default make a requst to otherdomain.com ? Is it allowed?

No. For security reasons

> What can be done to get response from otherdomain.com, if it is not
>   allowed ?

if you own the otherdomain.com you can use jsonp and some php stuffs.

```
http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/
```